# How to open specific user profile based on what is clicked on

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc

At first this sounded very simple, but actually I couldn't find a way to implement this.

I have Spring web app, with rest controllers and database. I have users in my web app and I want to open specific page in which details of that user will be shown. So how do I send information about what is clicked on (link to that specific user's details) to another page where the details about user are being displayed?

This is what I tried and when I load profile page nothing appears on it:
index.html

```
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="appController">

<head >
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/App.js"></script>
<p ng-click = "setProfileDetails(john)"><a href="profile.html">profile</a></p>
```

profile.html

Here I use the same `App.js` file so I can read the same controller.

```
<body ng-controller = "appController">
<div ng-model = "profileDetails">
{{profileDetails.username}}
</div>
</body>
```

App.js

```
$sopce.profileDetails = null;

$scope.setProfileDetails = function(username){
$http.get("services/rest/getUser/" + username).then(function(response){
$scope.profileDetails = response.data;
}, function(Response){
});
}
```

Comment: did you try spring security?

Comment: @Generic Yes, just started using it, but I don't know how to make use of it for this.

Comment: your concepts and logic are fine, your code doesn't work because most probably you have missed something tiny, post your app.js and index.html and your controller code. Use console logs to see what fails, API call something else

Comment: @rohanagarwal I didn't copy whole code, just typed part of it so people can see my idea, and I don't have errors in js, just the variable `userDetails` in controller is not initialized. I think it has to do something with js not being synchronous or something, because I am setting variable and displaying it at the same time.

Comment: have you checked response.data?

Comment: @rohanagarwal I get `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on jsp page:

```
<form action="user-details/${userid}">
//list of users or whatever you want
</form>
```

on controller

```
@RequestMapping("user-details/{userid}")
public String showUserDetails(@PathVariable int userid, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("userDetails",userDAO.getUserDetailsById(userid);
    return "/ac_user/user-details";
}
```

Comment: I'am trying to find a way to do this without jsp pages, only with html. Will do this way if I don't find another solution.

Comment: you can code that on html page also, will work how it should. Though, I would suggest you to use JSP page.

Comment: This should open jsp page when I post `user-details/userId` request right? And what should I exactly return in this method?

Comment: yes. "/ac_user/user-details" is the jsp page. user-details.jsp

Answer (score 1):

You should expose an endpoint which returns user details provided some user identifier like userId. So, when someone clicks on a user, send the userId to the API and retrieve the response and display it. You just need to make a simple API call. Details about your front-end implementation are missing.

Comment: I have rest service that gives me user details based on username, but that is not the problem. I don't know how to pass data from what is being clicked onto another page where I display details. I use html and angularjs for front-end.

Comment: use ng-click. Create a controller and a function inside it and call the function when user clicks.(Bind the function using ng-click). Inside the function, call the API, and bring the data and redirect to a template which you use to display user details. Use ng-model to bind API response to your template