# How to display different contents on the same destination page based on different source pages in spring MVC?

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, controller, request-mapping

A destination page can be reached from different source pages (by clicking on links or buttons). Based on the source page, contents of the destination page will be different. I want to keep the link of the destination page always the same. How to achieve this in spring MVC? Is there any way to associate the source page link with the `@RequestMapping` annotation? I also need to handle the back-end processing in the controller separately for each source page (when the page transition occurs).

For example, the destination page is `abc.jsp` . I prefer a single link for this page `/toabc` . The link of this page is in two other pages `a.jsp` and `b.jsp` by the `<a>` tag, so they can be clicked to navigate to `abc.jsp` .

Comment: Read my question and answer, if that is what you need.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45224059/how-to-open-specific-user-profile-based-on-what-is-clicked-on

Comment: Actually I ain't looking for any userid solution.

Comment: You say that you want the same destination page link always. Can you add parameters to the url?

Comment: There must be some way to work with the same destination page link.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use referer

```
String referrer = request.getHeader("referer"); //it has wrong spelling
```

From the https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.36

> The Referer[sic] request-header field allows the client to specify, for the server's benefit, the address (URI) of the resource from which the Request-URI was obtained (the "referrer", although the header field is misspelled.)

All you need is to add something like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/do")
public String do(@RequestHeader(value="referer") String referer)
```